# Loss is coming very high for object detection

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I am using total of 3000 images for training an ssd_inception_v2_coco as the object detection model.
I have set batch size as 4 because I don't have a high end GPU hence I am renting it for few hours and wanted to run the network for 40000 steps.
Till now the network has reached 15000 steps but the loss is very huge (4.12).
**My questions are:**

1. Is the high loss because of the low batch size?
2. If I am using a batch size very low then will it take like 100k steps to converge?

Answer (score 1):

Irrespectively of training the model in a more general sense, you are likely checking on your model's far too often to spot any actual performance increase.

More specifically, if performance metrics are being printed out every 5 batches for example, you are seeing a performance increase based on just `5 x 4 = 20` data samples which is way too low for a DL model to have learnt anything meaningful. In the case of a `batch_size = 256` the model would have seen $1260$ more samples than in your case.

I hope this helps.